# Fetching the right PID from Process.spawn

Tags: ruby

I am creating a CLI application using ruby. This app receives a path to an executable, runs it, fetches the PID and collects stack trace samples every N milliseconds in order to profile the executable.

I use `Process.spawn` like this:

```
pid = Process.spwan(ENV, executable)
```

The problem with `pid` is that it's not the executable's, but it is the PID of `sh -c <EXECUTABLE>`.

In order to fetch the right PID I use `pidof` after `Process.spawn` like this:

```
target_pid = `pidof -s #{executable}`
```

and then I use `target_pid` for profiling.

Is there a cleaner way to get `target_pid` using Ruby?

Comment: Do you need the run the command in a shell?  `The cmdname, arg1, ... form does not use the shell.` and you would get the right pid back.

Comment: @AllanWind the target executable is a cli app

Comment: Didn't answer the question but gave you both solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the shell then use either of these two forms of calling:

```
pid = Process.spwan(ENV, executable, '--arg1')
```

and if you have no arguments then you would need to use this format instead:

```
pid = Process.spwan(ENV, [executable, 'name of executable'])
```

If you need the shell then you need to modify your `executable` variable to do something along these lines

```
cmd & echo "pid=$!"; fg
```

which means run your command in the background, obtain the pid of it which you can somehow communicate to your ruby process, then put that process in the foreground again.